# What if the metatheory is itself intuitionistic?

Tags: reference-request, intuitionistic-logic, metalogic

Usually, even in intuitionistic logic, the metatheory is classical. That is, to give just one example, either something is a theorem of intuitionistic logic, or it is not. That is an example of a metatheoretic instance of the law of excluded middle. But, my main question is, has anyone introduced a truly intuitionistic logic, where even the metatheory is intuitionistic? I would like to see such a paper or a book that does that.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean. Most results I’ve seen on intuitionist logic are proved constructively. The only example I can think of where that isn’t the case is the completeness of Kripke models. There’s certainly nothing in the syntax of intuitionist logic that requires classical logic in the metatheory.

Comment: @MarkSaving is absolutely correct. That said, if you want a concrete example, Veldman's paper [*An intuitionistic completeness theorem for intuitionistic predicate logic*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2272955) may be of interest.